# В какой библиотеке находится all_cols?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook

Скинули ноутбук, при запуске выдается такая ошибка. Ранее нигде all_cols не определены. Это  какая-то стандартная вещь в питоне для использования в обработке таблиц?

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-35-2b0916366335> in <module>
>      17     for index,content in enumerate(rankings):
>      18         if(content == 1):
> ---> 19             best.append(all_cols[index])
>      20 
>      21     print('Optimal subset: ' + str(best))
> 
> NameError: name 'all_cols' is not defined
```

Comment: **find /any/path/to/check/ *.py | grep "all_cols"**

Comment: Похоже, что это список/кортеж, элементы из которого добавляются в `best`, должен быть объявлен где-то.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk, `git grep ...`  куда более интереснее.